# asp.net template field get cell text using find control doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know that this question was asked many times before but I couldn't find an answer which solves my problem.

I need to do something very basic and simple, I have a GridView which has a template field and I am trying to access a cell text in the GridView,

So I have tried the following:

C#

```
Label lbl = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].FindControl("lblSomething") as Label;
string customerName = lbl.Text;
```

html

```
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Item">
    <HeaderTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lblSomething" runat="server" Text="title" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Something" ForeColor="white"></asp:LinkButton><br />
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Something" AutoPostBack="false" Width ="60" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>                    
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("Something") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="80px" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

`lbl` returns null.

Can someone please explain to me how to use `FindControl`? Try to be as clear as you can.

Answer (score 2):

Your LinkButton is in the HeaderRow, not a normal row. You need to use FindControl on the header.

```
LinkButton lb = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("lblSomething") as LinkButton;
```

And make sure you cast the right type. You are searching for a Label, but `lblSomething` is a LinkButton.

Comment: great, and thanks for the quick response but I still don't get it let's say I am trying to access cell's text in the selectedRow, How can it be done?

Comment: Depends on how you are generating the columns. The `Text` property cannot be used with `TemplateField`. But you shouldn't have to since you can just as easily access the source data.